# How do I append an element with an object as contents in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have This simple HTML structure:

```
<div class="bg">
  <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/filename.mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>
<div class="bg">
  <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/filename.mp4"></source>
  </video>
</div>
```

I want to append, via jQuery, to every `<div class="bg"></div>`, a `<div class="cover"></div>` element, each with the video element as its content.

For this purpose, I did:

```
$('#full_slider').find('.bg').each(function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video');
    $(this).append('<div class="cover" /><div class="cover" /><div class="cover" />');
    $(this).find('.cover').html(video);
});
```

The code above (strangely) deletes the initial video, living me with:

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

The desired (expected) output is:

```
<div class="bg">
 <video muted loop autoplay>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="video/filename.mp4"></source>
  </video>
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div class="cover">
    <video muted="" loop="" autoplay="">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="video/eroi.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The description isn't very clear. To speed this up, what is the expected HTML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see if this is what you want? The idea is to `clone()` the video element since what was happening was it was just being `moved` to the contents of the `cover`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#full_slider').find('.bg').each(function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video').clone();
    $(this).append('<div class="cover" /><div class="cover" /><div class="cover" />');
    $(this).find('.cover').html(video);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="full_slider">
  <div class="bg">
    <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4"></source>
  </video>
  </div>
  <div class="bg">
    <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4"></source>
  </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need 3 copies of each video.

Comment: Ok updated. 3 copies is what you have now. I changed it when playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `$(this).append('<div class="cover" /><div class="cover" /><div class="cover" />');` your html is not correct, try changing it to `$(this).append('<div class="cover"></div>');` and add `$(this).html("");` to clear it before adding content

```js
$(".doit").on('click', function() {
  $('#full_slider').find('.bg').each(function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video');
    $(this).html("");
    $(this).append('<div class="cover"></div>');
    $(this).find('.cover').html(video);
    $(this).find('video').trigger('play');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="full_slider">
  <div class="bg">
    <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
  </video>
  </div>
  <div class="bg">
    <video muted loop autoplay>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></source>
  </video>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="doit">Do it</button>
```

Comment: Well the problem is in `$(this).append('<div class="cover" /><div class="cover" /><div class="cover" />');` the correct way of doing so is in the code snippet , keeping what you already have that mean keeping the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it. This is what your after

```
$('#full_slider > .bg').append("<div class='cover'/>");
$('#full_slider > .bg > .cover').html(video);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add a video to your existing HTML code, the best way to do it may not be to use jQuery to add it dynamically. jQuery should be used mainly for formatting AFAIK..... The easiest way for you may be to use Find and Replace using your editor. It's my opinion that it can save you overhead.....